# como puedo agregar dos eventos onclick a un boton?

Tags: javascript, html5

alguien sabe como podría hacer que un botón me cambie el texto en pantalla dependiendo del método elegido por el usuario verán me explico estoy haciendo una pagina que te pregunta que métodos de ordenamiento usar cuando lo eliges  ordenes con dicho metodo seleccionado ya funciona pero no logro hacer que el botón que tengo me active dos innerHTML distintos alguien sabe como podría quiero que si el usuario elige método burbuja el botón funciones para burbuja si elige mergesort funcione para mergesort

```js
var usuario = prompt("Dame el metodo a usar")

switch (usuario) 
{
 case "mergesort":
  if (usuario == "mergesort") {
   var ingresar = null;
   console.log('haz elegido el mergesort')
   function sub(){ingresar = document.getElementsByName("ingresar")[0].value.split(",").map(Number)};
   
   function mergeSort (array){
                 if (array.length === 1){
        return array;
     }
      var longitud = Math.floor(array.length / 2) 
      var derecha = array.slice(0, longitud) 
      var izquierda = array.slice(longitud)  
      
         return merge(mergeSort(izquierda), mergeSort(derecha));
        }
      
      function merge  (izquierda, derecha){
      var result = [];
      var il = ir = 0;

        while (il < izquierda.length && ir < derecha.length){
                 
                 if (izquierda[il] < derecha[ir]){
                   result.push(izquierda[il])
                   il++
                 } 
                 else{
                   result.push(derecha[ir])
                   ir++
                 }
     }
       return [...result,...izquierda.slice(il),...derecha.slice(ir)];
   }

  }
      

  break;
   
   case "bublesort":
       if (usuario == "bublesort") {
                var ingresar = null;
                console.log('haz elegido el burbuja')
                function sub(){ingresar = document.getElementsByName("ingresar")[0].value.split(",").map(Number)};
    function burbuja(arreglo){
  
       for(i=0;i<(arreglo.length-1);i++)
       for(j=0;j<(arreglo.length-i);j++){
           
           if(arreglo[j]>arreglo[j+1]){
                aux=arreglo[j];
                arreglo[j]=arreglo[j+1];
                arreglo[j+1]=aux;}}
    
       return arreglo
   }       
  }
     break;

 default:
  // statements_def
  break;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Proyecto</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
       <div class="container">  
            <textarea class="intro animated bounceInRight " name="ingresar" id="ingresar" placeholder="Aqui podras ingresar o generar numeros de forma aleatoria" ></textarea>
 
            <textarea class="out animated bounceInLeft " id="salida" placeholder="Aqui los podras ver ordenados"></textarea>
           </div>
           
           <div class="poder">     
       <button class="ingresar animated bounceInUp "type="submit" value="ordenar" 
              onclick="sub()
        document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML=mergeSort(ingresar)
        document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML=burbuja(ingresar)">Ordenar Numeros <i class="icon-pacman"></i>
    </button>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿no puedes crear un método que sea llamado por ambos botones? ya en el método validas que debe mostrar.

Comment: aunque es buena idea mi profesor, no quiere que sea de ese modo me dio unos parámetros algo complicados de cumplir

Comment: puedes especificar los parámetros que te dieron? así podemos ayudarte con tu respuesta

Comment: Te recomiendo que las funciones que tengas dentro de ese switch las definas fueras del switch, de lo contrario, si llamas a alguna que este en otra comprobación del switch (El cuál es el caso), no estará definida y el código no funcionará.

Answer (score 0):

Primero saca las funciones que tienes dentro del switch (Hazlas globales o por lo menos que esten fuerá del switch) y usalas dentro de tu switch:

```js
var usuario = prompt("Dame el metodo a usar")
console.log(`Haz elegido el metodo ${usuario}`);
var ingresar;
//Haz tu output global, talvez lo necesitaras usar en mas de una cosa. (No lo obtengas en una función)
var output = document.getElementById("salida");

function sub() {

  ingresar = document.getElementsByName("ingresar")[0].value.split(",").map(Number)

};

function mergeSort(array) {

  if (array.length === 1) {
    return array;
  }

  var longitud = Math.floor(array.length / 2)
  var derecha = array.slice(0, longitud)
  var izquierda = array.slice(longitud)

  return merge(mergeSort(izquierda), mergeSort(derecha));

}

function merge(izquierda, derecha) {

  var result = [];
  var il = ir = 0;

  while (il < izquierda.length && ir < derecha.length) {

    if (izquierda[il] < derecha[ir]) {
      result.push(izquierda[il])
      il++
    } else {
      result.push(derecha[ir])
      ir++
    }

  }

  return [...result, ...izquierda.slice(il), ...derecha.slice(ir)];
}

function burbuja(arreglo) {

  for (i = 0; i < (arreglo.length - 1); i++)
    for (j = 0; j < (arreglo.length - i); j++) {

      if (arreglo[j] > arreglo[j + 1]) {
        aux = arreglo[j];
        arreglo[j] = arreglo[j + 1];
        arreglo[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }

  return arreglo
}

//Mete tu switch (Comprobaciónes) dentro de una función
function usarMetodo() {

  sub();

  switch (usuario) {

    case "mergesort":

      if (usuario == "mergesort") {

        salida.value = mergeSort(ingresar);

      }


      break;

    case "bublesort":

      if (usuario == "bublesort") {

        salida.value = burbuja(ingresar);

      }

      break;

    default:
      console.log("El metodo elegido no es un metodo valido.");
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Proyecto</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <textarea class="intro animated bounceInRight " name="ingresar" id="ingresar" placeholder="Aqui podras ingresar o generar numeros de forma aleatoria"></textarea>

    <textarea class="out animated bounceInLeft " id="salida" placeholder="Aqui los podras ver ordenados"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="poder">
    <button class="ingresar animated bounceInUp " type="submit" value="ordenar" onclick = "usarMetodo();">Ordenar Numeros <i class="icon-pacman"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

No creo que sea necesario añadir dos eventos onclick a un boton para que te cambie el texto en pantalla dependiendo de si usaste un metodo u otro a dos "innerHTML", después de todo puedes simplemente decirle a cada uno de los  elementos a los que requieres cambiarles su valor en el switch que cambien su valor cada vez que se ejecuta la función usarMetodo, compruebas cual metodo es y ejecutas un ordenamiento u el otro y cambias el output con el atributo value y no con innerHTML. y el de los otros elementos que necesitas.

ah por cierto, en el onclick del boton, le cambie el valor que tenia a usarMetodo(), esta función es la encargada de ejecutar una función u otra y mostrar el resultado en pantalla.